# Xamarin Portable Library PCL Preprocessor Platform

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm trying to create and use de Portable library for a cross platform Xamarin.Forms. But the preprocessor for the platform doesn't seem set when I break in the code.

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE || __ANDROID__
  Debug.WriteLine("Passed");
#endif
```

Using step by step I can see all the code between the preprocessor condition be skipped (tried on Android and Windows Phone). But when I try the same thing in the start project it works.

In Visual Studio the code should be highlighted when active but it's not in the PCL.

The preprocessors defined in the startup project should be shared with the library, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCL doesn't work this way. 
Try this:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
...
if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
    Debug.WriteLine("I'm on Android");
else if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
    Debug.WriteLine("This is iOS");
```

Here (https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/)
you can find the appropriate Xamarin article. What you are trying to do is
Shared Assets approach and not PCL approach.

Comment: Is there anyway to create a platform ready library when you need different assemblies and references for each platform ?

Comment: PCL library IS platform ready... The whole point of it is that you can use the same assembly for all platforms. If you need different references/assemblies for each platform, you add them to your platform-specific project. If you think you need different references for each platform INSIDE your PCL than I guess something is wrong with your design. Unfortunately I can't be more specific without knowing what exactly you're triyng to do. Please clarify...

Comment: I changed my code and did everything with the .Net assembly it works now.